# R Cases won't recognize results of is.na()

Tags: r, switch-statement, warnings

I'm trying to create a factor from vector `d` that indicates whether each value of `d` is missing, less than `threshhold`, or greater than/equal to `threshhold`. I attempted with the following code, using the `cases` function from the `memisc` package.

```
threshhold = 5
d <- sample(c(1:10, NaN), 50, replace=TRUE)
d_case <- cases(
  is.na(d),
  d > threshhold,
  d <= threshhold
)
```

and got a warning: `In cases(is.na(d), d > threshhold,  :
  condition is.na(d) is never satisfied`.

I've also tried using assignment operators,

```
d_case <- cases(
  is.na(d)        -> 0,
  d > threshhold  -> 1,
  d <= threshhold -> 2
)
```

and got the same warning. I've checked, and `d` does contain `NaN` values, which `is.na()` should be returning as true (and is, when I check it outside of cases). Does anyone know why cases isn't working, or what I can do to get the indicator factor I need?

Comment: Where are you getting the `cases` function from? That's not part of base R. It would also help to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output to make it clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: For this simple example you could also use something like `as.numeric(x > threshold)`, adding 1 and then assigning `0` to `NA` elements if you want.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for that, I've edited my question to show that cases is from memisc, and have included code to generate sample data so that the problem is reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `?cases` according to the documenation you can do it like this

```
d <- c(-1:3,NA,1:2)
fun <- function(x){
  cases(
    is.na(x)        -> 0,
    x > threshhold  -> 1,
    x <= threshhold -> 2
  )
}
d_case <- fun(d)
d_cases
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
addNA(as.factor(d>threshold))
....
Levels: FALSE TRUE <NA>
```